# Unable to get a drop down menu option to open a new web page

Tags: html

I have a drop down menu that currently opens results and displays them in an iframe. I removed the script for the iframe because I wanted to see how the page styled just opening in the same window. I tried using target_"self" to have the link open in the same window but that's not doing the trick either.

At first I thought the 'blank' in the select function was causing it to default to a new window but that's not it.  I've only updated the link to current projects.  I didn't want to change everything until I knew it worked.  That link does work, but it just opens in a new browser window.  I only put the form code here.

```
<form>
  <p><b>Our Projects<br/><br/></b>
      <select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CurrentProjects.php" target="_self">Current Projects</option>
      <option value="ProjectsInFinalReview">In Final Review</option>
      <option value="DeliveredProjects">Delivered</option>
      <option value="CompletedProjects">Completed Projects</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? For the url to be followed on the same window (like a link)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to get the current page to update to the selected option instead of opening a new tab, change your previous

`window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')`

to

`window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')`:

Ultimately to:

```
<form>
  <p><b>Our Projects<br/><br/></b>
      <select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CurrentProjects.php">Current Projects</option>
      <option value="ProjectsInFinalReview">In Final Review</option>
      <option value="DeliveredProjects">Delivered</option>
      <option value="CompletedProjects">Completed Projects</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</form>
```

If you are looking for more control, you could use a target attribute on the options to drive the target for the `window.open`, giving you the ability to say some options open new windows, and some change the current window.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vandsh/fkj7vgp4/

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I want it to open in the same tab.